# IE8 64-bit Edition does not support iframe

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am plotting charts by including another charting page in iFrame. This runs fine in IE8 32 bit with 128 bit cipher strength and also in other browsers like chrome and firefox but it does not work in IE8 64 bit edition with 256-bit Cipher Stength

I tried the link below from W3Schools of iFrame, it also works in my other browsers but not in IE8 64-edition with 256-bit Cipher Strength.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe

Please tell me how can I fix this.

Comment: Can u browse this http://www.quirksmode.org/iframetest.html?

Comment: thanks Boris, when I open your link then it display no in text field.So now what can I do

Comment: okay, that fine, when change security settings then run fun.